# Не работает сравнение в ReportViewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Есть выражение `=Iif(Fields!COEF.Value = 0, 0, Fields!SUM.Value - Fields!SUM.Value / Fields!COEF.Value)`
Всегда срабатывает только вторая ветка, с выражением.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ скрывался в выражении... IIF, не знаю уж кто его проектировал, проверяет корректность обеих частей в любом случае, вне зависимости от условия. В данном случае он делил на 0 и соответственно получал ошибку.